# Custom Tab Bar Controller Causing Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Hi I have been having issues with a NSString memory leak in my IOS app. I am starting to believe this leak is being caused by my custom tab bar controller due to a tab bar being involved within the leaks stack trace. I am unsure of where I am going wrong and would appreciate it if someone could quickly check my custom class? Thanks!

Here is the class, the .h file has not been modified in anyway!

```
#import "CustomTabBarController.h"

@interface CustomTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation CustomTabBarController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
      UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
      UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
      UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tbcb"];
      self.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:132.0/255.0 green:64.0/255.0 blue:49.0/255.0 alpha:1];
      [self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:bg];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"Breakfast";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"Lunch";
    tabBarItem3.title = @"Dinner";

      tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bf"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
      tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bfs" ] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];


     tabBarItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"l"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
     tabBarItem2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ls" ] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];


     tabBarItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"d"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
     tabBarItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ds" ] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Below is the stack trace!

[image]

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak? Neither the stack trace nor the code you posted provides any indication of a leak. Use the leak template of instruments and 'move' through your app - if it reveals a leak, pls post the results

Comment: @tobi hi! The stack trace was taken from a leak which appeared when switching tabs on my app! The leak was found using the leaks instrument!